# SQL Join with table including from/to values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm working with a 3rd-party SQL Server database, containing the two tables below (simplified), which I'd like to join into a single view.

The **Document** table contains the following columns:
**ID** primary key
"other columns".

The **DocumentTag** table contains the following columns: 
**FromDocumentID** 
**ToDocumentID** 
**Tag**.

How do I create a view of the form **Document.ID**, **Tag**, "other columns"?
Join each document its tag (yes, with repetitions) instead of looking for the right ID range in the **Document Tag** table.

[EDIT] an example:

Document table

```
ID    | Description | Owner ....
------+-------------+---------
1     | blah        | me 
2     | blah 2      | me
3     | blah 3      | Alice
4     | blah 4      | Bob
5     | blah blah   | me 
6     | blah blah 2 | Bob
7     | blah blah 3 | Alice
8     | blah blah 4 | Alice
```

Document Tag table

```
FromDocumentID | ToDocumentID | Tag         | ...
---------------+--------------+-------------+----
1              | 3            | Bananas
4              | 4            | Crocodiles
5              | 5            | Bananas
6              | 8            | Donuts
```

What I would like to have is

```
ID    | Description | Owner  | Tag      | ....
------+-------------+--------+----------+-----
1     | blah        | me     | Bananas
2     | blah 2      | me     | Bananas
3     | blah 3      | Alice  | Bananas
4     | blah 4      | Bob    | Crocodiles
5     | blah blah   | me     | Bananas
6     | blah blah 2 | Bob    | Donuts
7     | blah blah 3 | Alice  | Donuts
8     | blah blah 4 | Alice  | Donuts
```

Comment: seems pretty simple though I'm dubious about effective it's going to be. Do you want a row for each link e.g. (Doc1, Doc1ToDoc2Tag) and (Doc2, Doc1ToDoc2Tag) or one row per pairing e.g. Doc1, Doc1ToDoc2Tag, Doc2

Comment: This makes so little sense.  What is "instead of right ID range"?  Exactly what do you want to join on?

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected results, or create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tag applies to many documents by range

```
select D.ID, T.Tag, D.Other1, D.Other2
from Document D
left join DocumentTag T on D.ID between T.FromDocumentID and T.ToDocumentID
```

If the tag applies to 2 specific documents by ID. This also shows the creation of a view

```
create View DocumentWithTag
as
select D.ID, T.Tag, D.Other1, D.Other2
from Document D
left join DocumentTag T on D.ID in (T.FromDocumentID, T.ToDocumentID)
```